# ConstraintLayout how to spread the remainder view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

It's my first time working with `ContraintLayouts` and I need some help

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with a `TextView`, a `LinearLayout` and a `RecyclerView` and I want that the RecyclerView spreads out to fill it's parent, without having to use weightned chains because I don't have a ratio relation between all Views. How can I do this ?

TextView height should be `wrap_content`
LinearLayout height should be `wrap_content`
Recycler height should be "Take the rest of the space"

I've been trying to use chain spreading but it doesn't seem to have any effect

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close"
            android:id="@+id/headline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I'm looking for

EDIT: My Recycler View is Wrapping up only, so I have a tone of blank space

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the layout_height of recyclerView as 0dp, like this:

```
layout_height = "0dp"
```

and also give this as you haven't given the bottom constraint:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: so its not spreading?. I mean its not taking the entire layout?. Can you tell me whats happening?

Comment: @PrashanthVerma It's only wrapping

Comment: I'll accept this one because he pointed out the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` first. I checked the edit times with the answer times in case anyone was wondering

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Here you go, just copy paste it and check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `Contraint_End` and `Constraint_start` don't do much, only bottom fixed it

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close"
        android:id="@+id/headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: `weight` wasn't necessary, `constraint_bottom` was the key

Comment: Thanks for your help